# Custom redirect to the next available nested route

Tags: nuxtjs3

In Nuxt3, given the working example below:

**Path:**
`/mypost/3/item-4`

Where "3" and "4" are dynamic.

**Files (in `pages`):**

```
/mypost/index.vue           // Shows grid view of mypost's

/mypost/[postid].vue            // Contains <NuxtPage /> which renders child route content

/mypost/[postid]/index.vue      // mypost details page

/mypost/[postid]/item-[itemid].vue  // mypost sub-item details page
```

### QUESTION

If user invokes a 404 error anywhere in the nested chain, like...

---

**Case A**

Error: `/mypost/3/something-triggering-404`

Ideally redirect to: `/mypost/3`

**Case B**

Error: `/mypost/3/item-4/another-404`

Ideally redirect to: `/mypost/3/item-4`

---

What's the best way to have a custom 404 handling that can satisfy redirects to the next available nested route?

Is there a way to have "context-sensitive" redirects like this defined purely by file-structure (as all routing is defined by files structure) as opposed to have a custom middleware (or whatever) living somewhere else in the codebase.

I suppose, at the very least, perhaps: A custom route definition could live in the root `/something/index.vue` (Composition API) ? I don't like this either as it could be easily overlooked.

Looking for recommendations.

**Currently:** User is presented with static global 404 error page, which is generic and does not redirect specially to the next available nested route level.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Nuxt has the dynamic error handling for nested routes but since you have a full control of your application, you can use the [error page](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#rendering-an-error-page)(`~error.vue`) to control the navigation.

On the `~error.vue` page, you can track the full path by using the `useRoute()`  function. Then use the `split` method. Then, you can check if the params starts with the `item-` and check if the main path is `my-post`. Also, ensure to check that this codes will run only if the page is 404, you can check if by using the `error` object props.

Something like this.

`~error.vue`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
    error: Object
})

const route = useRoute()
const pathParts = route.fullPath.split('/')
const mainPath = pathParts[1]
const postId = pathParts[2]
const itemItemId = pathParts[3]

if (props.error!.statusCode === 404) {
    if (itemItemId.includes('item-')) {
        navigateTo(`/${mainPath}/${postId}/${itemItemId}`)
    } else if (mainPath === 'my-post') {
        navigateTo(`/${mainPath}/${postId}`)
    }
}

</script>
```

I have a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-bpanch?file=error.vue) but for some reasons the redirect does not work on stackblitz but 100% working on local. See screen record https://streamable.com/mfvjpp